# Cypress: Prevent open new tab with link dynamically created and clicked

Tags: cypress

I want to test a file download. It is made programmatically on click a button that uses this function:

```
export function downloadURI(uri, target) {
  const link = document.createElement('a')
  if (target) link.target = target

  link.href = uri
  link.click()
}
```

The problem is that when you do `cy.click()` on that button the new tab is opened and the tests fail. I am checking that the download is successful by asserting the loading modal is visible after clicking the button (while the file is being generated via an HTTP request) and is Not visible after the download was generated.

How can I prevent this tab from opening so that the tests do not fail?

Comment: May I know how your application works? Does it come back to the normal tab after download is completed? If so, you can try wait(), instead of trying to prevent the tab from opening

Comment: You can download .pdf and .xlsx files. I call the function like this `downloadURI('https://random_url", "_blank")`. When is a .pdf the browser open the file in a new tab and focus on that tab (browsers are now pdf readers too). When is a .xlsx a tab is opened and closed instantly and it downloads the file, so here the normal tab loses and gain focus (very fast).

Comment: may be you can use cy.visit() to come back to your normal url and continue tetsing from there. Just an option

Comment: It does not work, after the new tab get opened I can't execute any other command/assert.

Answer (score 6):

This works for me:

```
cy.get('a').invoke('removeAttr', 'target').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [official document](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/trade-offs.html#Multiple-tabs) it says that cypress does not support multiple tabs testing.
Also there is a [recipe](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/testing-dom__tab-handling-links) including 3 solutions about how to handle this.
Have a read and see if it can help.

Comment: I do not want to test multiple tabs.

Comment: Are you testing the loading modal after click the button? If so you might do this in two steps. First is change the onclick attribute on the button like this :       cy.get('button').invoke('attr','onclick','downloadURI("", "")');   cy.get("button").click()   In this case it only click the button but goes nowhere so you can test the load modal.    Secondly use Cypress request to the url to test the link is working.